# my pro just shows client side validation errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i use @Html.ValidationMessage("username") to check duplicate username.
and it is working.
but when i have serverside validation error & clientside validation error together , it just shows clientside error .i wanna **both** errors can to appear.

@Html.ValidationMessage("username") alone works , but when i have forexample email required error too , @Html.ValidationMessage("username") doesn't show and just email error is shows.

```
   //client
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email, new { @class = "group", @placeholder = "*  enter email" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)

   //server
    @Html.ValidationMessage("username")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username, new {@id="group" , @class = "input-block-level", @placeholder = "* enter username" })
```

Comment: -1: simply for tag-spam

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior for client-side validation: it prevents a form post on error, because it can very quickly determine that the input would be invalid.

If you don't want the client-side validation to run, you can disable it and rely on the corresponding server-side validation to generate the same error message (assuming you are validating server-side, which you should be).

Comment: no, i wanna when i click submit button , both error can to appear. these are not related to each other . server and client are diffrent.

Comment: @niknaz: Client-side validation should be a subset of server-side validation. Otherwise users can disable javascript and send invalid values to your server. On the other hand, if you are doing server-side checking, you should be able to safely disable client-side checking and allow the server to send back all the validation messages at once. The only advantage to client-side validation is that it avoids the round-trip to the server. If you need the round-trip for some validation, then client-side validation isn't helping you.